# How to show date/time in local time zone in Data Studio from UTC timestamp in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I want Google Data Studio reports to show sales data (including a sales-by-hour heat map report) using the user's local time zone. I'm storing the data in BigQuery and the timestamp field is stored as UTC.

Per [Data Studio Help](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549?hl=en&ref_topic=9216937), it sounds like the timestamp should be stored as UTC (which I'm doing). I assumed Data Studio was smart enough to convert UTC to the user's local time zone, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Everything is working perfectly except the hours on the heat map report show as 8:00-17:00 instead of 12:00-21:00. It's showing UTC instead of EST (my time zone), and I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Does Data Studio automatically adjust the report data based on the user's time zone? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, are there any workarounds that would support users from multiple time zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second argument of the TIMESTAMP() function to convert the UTC timestamp to a specific time zone. Here's [a list of time zones](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188) supported by Big Query.

```
ex. SELECT TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 15:30:00", "America/New_York") AS timestamp_in_est;

+-------------------------+
| timestamp_in_est        |
+-------------------------+
| 2008-12-25 20:30:00 UTC | 
+-------------------------+
```

Data Studio does not adjust timestamps based on timezones. All timestamps are displayed in UTC unless specified.

Answer (score 3):

The [17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020) to Google Data Studio introduced updates to Dates and Times as well as new functions and ways to works with Dates and Times which includes **Time Zones**.

### 0) [Upgrade the Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926419/12892553)

Ensure that the **Date Time** field has been upgraded to to the newer Date Time field type.

Added a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 1) `EST`

This [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) obtains the difference in `SECOND` between `UTC` and `EST` by using the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) function, and subsequently subtracts the difference with the Date Time field (called `DateTimeField` in this Report):

```
PARSE_DATETIME(
    "%s",
    CAST(CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%s",DateTimeField)AS NUMBER) - DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME("UTC"),CURRENT_DATETIME("EST"), SECOND)AS TEXT))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c28ab1d9-af65-4f3e-bbe8-e86c7786511c) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution was convert the time to MICRO and then add 1 hour(MICRO).

```
TODATE(((name_of_column)+(3600000000)),'MICROS','%Y%m%d%H%M')
```