# Convert date field from GCP to DataStudio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio, date-conversion

Google Cloud Platform.
This file contains a field with this format **Saturday Jul 24 2021 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure dâ€™Ã©tÃ© dâ€™Europe centrale)**

I would like to use this field for a report in DataStudio. However this field is not consistent as a date.

I am trying to find a way to convert that field into a date.

I have tried PARSE_DATE or PARSEDATETIME() but no resolution at this time.

Answer (score 1):

generate a `date_loc` for the local time:

```
PARSE_DATETIME(
r"%B %d %Y %H:%M:%S",
REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_text,r"day (.*:..) .*[\+-]") 
)
```

The regex removes everyting but the date and time.

Another field `date_offset`  for the offset:

```
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_text, r"([\+\-]\d\d)") AS number )
```

For the date in UTC, please create this field

```
PARSE_DATETIME(
    "%s",
    CAST(
        CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%s",date_loc)AS NUMBER) 
        - date_offset *3600
        as text )
    )
```

This last formula is from here: [How to show date/time in local time zone in Data Studio from UTC timestamp in Big Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462206/how-to-show-date-time-in-local-time-zone-in-data-studio-from-utc-timestamp-in-bi)